# How to avoid function result being destroyed by Free inside function?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle

This code creates an AV:

```
function PAIsMainAppWindow(Wnd: THandle): Boolean;
var
  ParentWnd: THandle;
  ExStyle: DWORD;
begin
  if IsWindowVisible(Wnd) then
  begin
    ParentWnd := THandle(GetWindowLongPtr(Wnd, GWLP_HWNDPARENT));
    ExStyle := GetWindowLongPtr(Wnd, GWL_EXSTYLE);
    Result := ((ParentWnd = 0) or (ParentWnd = GetDesktopWindow)) and
      ((ExStyle and WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW = 0) or (ExStyle and WS_EX_APPWINDOW <> 0));
  end
  else
    Result := False;
end;

function PAEnumTaskWindowsProc(Wnd: THandle; List: TStrings): Boolean; stdcall;
var
  Caption: array [0..1024] of Char;
begin
  if PAIsMainAppWindow(Wnd) and (GetWindowText(Wnd, Caption, SizeOf(Caption)) > 0) then
    List.AddObject(ExtractFileName(GetProcessNameFromWnd(Wnd)), Pointer(Wnd));
  Result := True;
end;

function PAGetTaskWindowHandleFromProcess(const AProcessName: string): THandle;
var
  sl: TStringList;
  i: Integer;
begin
  Result := 0;

  sl := TStringList.Create(True); // stringlist owns objects
  try
    if EnumWindows(@PAEnumTaskWindowsProc, LPARAM(sl)) then
    begin
      for i := 0 to sl.Count - 1 do
      begin
        if SameText(AProcessName, sl[i]) then
        begin
          Result := THandle(sl.Objects[i]);
          BREAK;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    sl.Free; // AV!
  end;
end;

ChromeHandle := PAGetTaskWindowHandleFromProcess('chrome.exe');
```

It is clear that the AV occurs because freeing the stringlist also destroys the function result. But how can this be avoided?

Comment: There is no need to own objects. They are not objects, they have not heap memory allocated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, let's look at the actual code. The string list does not hold objects. It holds window handles. So `OwnsObjects` is simply not appropriate. That's going to assume that the things in `Objects[]` are Delphi instances of classes, and call `Free` on these instances. That is where the failure occurs.

You don't own these window handles, and you therefore should not attempt to destroy them.

So, don't set `OwnsObjects` to `True` and the problem goes away. That is replace this line:

```
sl := TStringList.Create(True); // stringlist owns objects
```

with this:

```
sl := TStringList.Create;
```

Further, you are casting these objects to `THandle`. That is wrong, not that it actually matters. Semantically though, these are window handles, so cast them to `HWND`. Indeed, everywhere you use `THandle` you should use `HWND`.

There are other errors too. When you call use `GetWindowText` you pass the size of the buffer rather than its length. That means you are lying about how long the buffer is. Because these are wide characters, the buffer is half as long as you claim it to be. Looking for windows that are parented to the desktop window feels wrong.

---

Let's assume, for the sake of argument, that your string list really did contain objects. In that case, and in an ideal world, the string list class would offer an `Extract` method which is the conventional method to remove an object from an owning container without destroying that object. So instead you can perform the `OwnsObjects` shuffle.

```
if SameText(AProcessName, sl[i]) then
begin
  sl.OwnsObjects := False;
  Result := TSomeObject(sl.Objects[i]);
  sl.Objects[i] := nil;
  sl.OwnsObjects := True;
  BREAK;
end;
```

If you'd rather, you can set `OwnsObjects` to be `False` when you create the string list, and only set it to `True` just before you call `Free` on it.

Comment: David, thanks for the extensive explanation! How would you solve the GetWindowText problem?

Comment: You can find out in the docs for that function. They tell you to pass the length of the buffer. Yours has length 1025.